# An example for finding an explicit definition of "structure maps"

Tags: abstract-algebra, lie-algebras

By googling, I found only [What is meant by a “structure map”?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/839026/what-is-meant-by-a-structure-map). But I could not understand that for my example as follows: Let $L$ be a Lie algebra over $K$, and view $K$ as a trivial $L$-module (that is, define $x \dot a=0$ for all $x \in L$, $a \in K$). In other words, we have a trivial structure map. What does it mean when that $\rho : L \to K$ is a structure map? Does it mean that $\rho$ is just a Lie algebra homomorphism?

Comment: Are you sure that it's a map $L \to K$?

Comment: Could you give a link to the text, where you have seen this? Otherwise it is hard to clarify it.

Comment: @DietrichBurde  https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/372579/confusion-regarding-the-augmentation-map-of-lie-algebras?rq=1    This is about augmentation map

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think I've ever seen this in the context of Lie algebras; only like this for associative algebras, where the homomorphism is a ring homomorphism and the map is going the other way. [See Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Associative_algebra#From_ring_homomorphisms), but essentially, for an associative $K$-algebra $A$, the $K$-action on $A$ can be defined by a ring homomorphism $\phi:K \to A$ where for $k \in K$ and $a \in A$ the action is $k.a = \phi(k)a$.

[See this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Canonical_map) too for a more general consideration of "*structure maps*".

Comment: In your second link, it says "structure map or structure morphism; the map or morphism that comes with the given structure on the object.", sadly , I can not understand what they mean by  comes with the given structure on the object?

Comment: Each algebraic object is "a set with some structure." You could always list that structure explicitly (if $A$ is a $K$-algebra, list how every element of $K$ acts on each element of $A$), but often you can specify this structure in an equivalent way using a function of some kind ($\phi$ in this case). So for your case, the Lie algebra $L$ has the structure of a $K$-module (since it's a vector space). How could you capture this information of $L$ being a $K$-module using a function? This is the something I've never seen before, and can't immediately think of.

Answer (score 0):

Maps from Lie algebras to the *ground field* usually are forms, e.g., the trace form $\rho\colon L\times L\rightarrow K$, given by
$$
(X,Y)\mapsto \operatorname{tr}(XY),
$$
or the Killing form $\rho\colon L\times L\rightarrow K$, given by
$$
(X,Y)\mapsto \operatorname{tr}({\rm ad}(X){\rm ad}(Y)).
$$ In some translations into English I have seen the word "structure map" here, which is not quite the correct translation. A link to your source text would be helpful, of course.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I saw this map, when I was studying augmentation map in Lie algebra, here is the link which is also in Mathstackexchange : https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/372579/confusion-regarding-the-augmentation-map-of-lie-algebras?rq=1

Comment: I see. There it seems to mean just the action $\mathfrak{g}\times M\mapsto M$ for a $\mathfrak{g}$-module $M$, in this case for the trivial module $M=K$. So perhaps he wrote "structure map" for the trivial module structure. Anyway, you should have linked to this question from the beginning, or even make a comment there. Posting it here without context makes it difficult.